# Send invitation to attendees

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am creating an event in Google calendar. My requirement is that i don't want to send the Google invitation to some attendees and want send the Google invitation to others attendees. But in Google calendar creating event we have to set the option as true or false for the invitation to all the attendees. So is there any alternative to send the invitation only to some attendees. Lets take as example i want to call 5 attendees but want to send the Google calendar invitation to only 3 attendees and for rest attendees i don't want to send the calendar invitation.